# Как перевести массив байтов в строку UTF-8 в Visual C++

Tags: c++, utf-8, unicode

Имею массив байтов, байты в массив записаны в кодировке UTF-8, соответственно нужно как-то преобразовать байты в строку такой же кодировке, каким образом это можно сделать?

```
unsigned char binarr[1024]; // условно этот массив заполнен байтами считанными из файла
string test = ""; // в эту строку желаю сунуть символы преобразованные из массива байтов
```

Вот так выглядит эта процедура в C#:

```
 byte[] foo;
 string test = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(foo);
```

Comment: Что вы обозначаете словом "массив" и словом "строка"? Добавьте пример кода. Вообще говоря, строка - это последовательность символов. А массив - это последовательность чего угодно.

Comment: @yeputons добавил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::string` это и так набор `char`. Т.е. однобайтовый набор. Главное тут понимать, что отдельно взятый элемент такой строки (например, с помощью `operator[]`) не обязан быть валидным символом, т.к. UTF-8 многобайтовая кодировка. Заполнить же `std::string` из массива можно [соответствующим конструктором](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/), например так:

```
std::string test(binarr, размер_полезных_данных_массива);
```

А вот как интерпретировать этот набор уже совсем дело другое. То есть зависит от того, как дальше вы хотите работать со строкой `test`.

Comment: таки получилось интерпретировать этим методом

Answer (score 1):

Пример работающего кода:

```
wchar_t wctxt[512];
char    mbtxt[256];

char *utf8_to_oem(const char *s)
{
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8,0,s,strlen(s),wctxt,256);
    CharToOemW(wctxt,mbtxt);
    return mbtxt;
}
```

Или тебе наоборот нужно?